# knitr, lavaan, and subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, knitr, r-lavaan

I am getting an error, `Error in lines[[i]] : subscript out of bounds` when trying to knit a chunk that reads in a model from an external file and then fits the model in `lavaan`.

I create the model in a `.R` file:

```
model <- readLines(con = textConnection('
  depression =~ thoughts + pain + brain + use + suic + talk + sitalone +         
                headaches + app + heart + cheek + cry + sleep + disob + cold +
                liedown + worries + alone + annoyed + holdhead + drinkal +
                insult + greet + think + mutter + trust + donoth + sad + bad +
                weak + notalk + forget + crycont + livedie
  '))

cat(model, file = 'scripts/mod.lav.f1.0', sep = '\n')
```

When running the `.R` file, it puts the following in the `scripts/mod.lav.f1.0` file:

```
depression =~ thoughts + pain + brain + use + suic + talk + sitalone +         
              headaches + app + heart + cheek + cry + sleep + disob + cold +
              liedown + worries + alone + annoyed + holdhead + drinkal +
              insult + greet + think + mutter + trust + donoth + sad + bad +
              weak + notalk + forget + crycont + livedie
```

My `.rnw` file then reads in the `scripts/mod.lav.f1.0` that specifies my model.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<cfa, include=FALSE, tidy=FALSE>>=
# read in model from file
 mod.1f.0 <- readLines("scripts/mod.lav.f1.0")
# fit the model
 fit.1f.0 <- cfa(mod.1f.0, data = mydata, ordered=items)
@

\end{document}
```

The problematic statement in the chunk seems to be `fit.1f.0 <- cfa(mod.1f.0, data = mydata, ordered=items)`. When knitting the document, I get an error: `Error in lines[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`.

I am able to run the chunk in `R` without any problems. The model is stored in `mod.1f.0` and the fit is stored in `fit.1f.0`.

Any thoughts about what is causing this error?

Comment: We do not know what `mydata` or `items` is, so this is not a reproducible example. Can you provide a minimal self-contained example? You may also provide `library(knitr); sessionInfo()` and `traceback()` in the R session after the error occurs.

Comment: thanks, @Yihui. someone sent me another example that I was able to run, so I decided to delete my cache and all of the hidden project files that RStudio creates. it worked. prior to doing this I had only tried restarting RStudio. I'll close this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone sent me another example that I was able to run, so I decided to delete my cache and all of the hidden project files that RStudio creates. It worked. Prior to doing this I had only tried restarting RStudio.